# How can I convert analog voltage to PWM converter just by changing the input voltage

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, pwm, output, input

Which is used to convert analog input signal to PWM output. How can I vary the output with the input? How I can vary duty cycle?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings so far in considerable detail with a schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is building a DC-DC PSU PWM controller from discrete components a terrible idea?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/481010/is-building-a-dc-dc-psu-pwm-controller-from-discrete-components-a-terrible-idea) - see my answer.

Comment: You cannot begin without specs.  % min, max etc

Answer (score 0):

Look at the LTC6992, it converts voltage to PWM.

[image]

[image]
Source: https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc6992-1.html#product-evaluationkit

Comment: The capacitor and the resistor(Rset) is inbuilt in IC or have to provide externally

Comment: Rset is the one shown above in the diagram, that is all you need to set the frequency

Comment: Man, the price! I am amazed